# How to Use ngRepeat with Open Layers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3

I'm doing a project using AngularJS 1.5.8 and OpenLayers3.

I'm able to display the map and set the various map components. However when I set a control on the map that has either ng-repeat or ng-if directives, nothing is displayed. When I test the code outside of the map (not as a control) it works fine.

I have already looked at the [angular-openlayers-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) project but I think it has too little activity to depend on it for my project.

The JSFiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecszdd4y/40/). And the same code below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.18.2/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.18.2/ol.css"></link>
<style>
     .lister {
         top: 5em;
         left: 0.5em;
     }
</style>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MapsController">

        <div id="map" class="map"></div>

        <div id="lister" class="lister ol-unselectable ol-control">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showMarkerPopup($index)">
      {{item.name}}
            </div> 
        </div>

        <div id="other" class="other ol-unselectable ol-control">
            Other Object
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MapsController',['$scope','$window','$compile',function($scope,$window,$compile){
   var lister = angular.element(document.querySelector('#lister'));
  $compile(lister)($scope);

  var listerControl = new $window.ol.control.Control({
    element: $window.document.getElementById('lister')
  });

  $scope.items = [{
    name: "ball",
    color: "blue"
  }, {
    name: "tree",
    color: "green"
  }, {
    name: "house",
    color: "red"
  }];

  $window.map = new $window.ol.Map({
    layers: [new $window.ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new $window.ol.source.OSM()
    })],
    target: 'map',
    view: new $window.ol.View({
      center: window.ol.proj.transform([36.823219, -1.288811], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 10
    })
  });

  $window.map.addControl(listerControl);

}]);
```

The other control I have placed works fine. And any other that have angular bindings except the ng-repeat and ng-if directives.

Help me look at what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure it out. I went with a custom directive as follows:

```
    app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
                function(scope) {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                },
                function(value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
        )};
}]);
```

And changed the control element to:

```
<div id="lister" class="lister ol-control">
    <div style="overflow:auto; max-height: 400px;" compile="item_list" ></div>
</div>
```

The working JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maxuville/y6m89uj7/)